# Exist an ob-erlang for src code block on org mode

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, erlang-mode

I'm looking for an ob-erlang library in order to execute erlang in source code blocks in org-mode; I looked on  
the language table, googled and on github and I didn't fin anything for erlang.

I know there is distel and edtgs for interacting with erlang. and also elixir has an ob-elixir. So maybe it should not be so difficult to write one for erlang. Models exist but exists any how to in order to write ob-anylanguage?

Comment: I don't know erlang. But I have already defined some `org-babel-execute:...` functions. It is quite simpe on org-babel side (I don't know the erlang side). The major mode for erlang is `erlang-mode`. So you must define `org-babel-execute:erlang`. You get the source code block body and the header line parameters as arguments and the return value determines the return value of the source block. You should take a look on the already existing `org-babel-execute:...` functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/xfwduke/ob-erlang

just implemented it.
you can try and give me some feedback :)